# How to find datasheet or pinout for this DC-DC IC? OB2560NAP

Tags: dc-dc-converter, datasheet

I have this power board on a WiFi extender and I'm trying to find the datasheet for this IC.[image]

I believe this is the switching IC that generates the low 3.3V voltage from the high ~220V input voltage after passing through a coil and a capacitor

I cannot find anything for L23371 but I see listings for OB2560NAP online on Google on Chinese sites. I cannot find a datasheet for the chip anywhere - is this some standard chip pinout that I'm perhaps not searching the right words for? or is this chip really that elusive?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a chip made by Shanghai-based OB(On-Bright Elec). [Datasheet](https://taoic.oss-cn-hangzhou.aliyuncs.com/6895/product/lisuo_1590723805000.pdf) here.

[image]

In general the right-hand portion of the part number refers to the package and rated temperature range, and possibly other kinds of variants, so try omitting it.

Here's the [pinout](https://www.on-bright.com/en/index/product/detail/cid/132/id/353.shtml) of the DIP version, which just doubles up on a couple of the pins (the higher current ones):

[image]

Comment: Thanks very much, it looks like exactly what I'm looking for. I was slightly confused as the 6 pin doesn't have the FET's embedded in the package, and the DIP8 one does.

Comment: @QuickishFM Kind of sloppy that they give them almost the same part number.